# Writing to file gives only new line on first execution

Tags: python

First time I execute this program, the resulting file does not have anything in it besides a new line. But the second time I execute it, it writes to 'out.txt' correctly, but the new line from the first execution is still there. Why does it not work correctly the first time?

```
bhaarat = open('bhaarat.txt', 'r+')
bhaarat_read = bhaarat.read()

out = open('out.txt', 'r+')
out_read = out.read()

bhaarat_split = bhaarat_read.split()

for word in bhaarat_split:
    if word.startswith('S') or word.startswith('H'):
        out.write(word + "\n")

bhaarat.write('\n23. English\n')
print out_read
print bhaarat_read

bhaarat.close()
out.close()
```

Comment: Could you dump the content of your file in order to see the structure ?

Comment: I apologize, I'm quite new at this so I don't really know what you mean. Do you mean 'cat file' to look at its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with Windows. The workaround ([see python mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2005-August/029886.html)) is to use

```
f.seek(f.tell())
```

between calls to `read()` and `write()` on a file `f` that was opened with one of the `+` options.

Adapted to your problem you have to call `bhaarat.seek(bhaarat.tell())` after first reading the file with `bhaarat_read = bhaarat.read()` and before writing to it with `bhaarat.write('\n23. English\n')`. The same for your `out`.

In Python3 this problem is fixed, so one more reason to switch :)

---

EDIT
The following code works for me. The files `bhaarat.txt` and `out.txt` must both be present.

```
bhaarat = open('bhaarat.txt', 'r+')
bhaarat_read = bhaarat.read()
bhaarat.seek(bhaarat.tell())
out = open('out.txt', 'r+')
out_read = out.read()
out.seek(out.tell())
bhaarat_split = bhaarat_read.split()

for word in bhaarat_split:
    if word.startswith('S') or word.startswith('H'):
        out.write(word + "\n")

bhaarat.write('\n23. English\n')
print out_read
print bhaarat_read

bhaarat.close()
out.close()
```

Comment: bhaarat.seek(f.tell()) gave me an error, so I tried bhaarat.seek(bhaarat.tell()). I'm not sure if that's correct.
However, I'm getting the same problem...

Comment: @user69498 That was an error in my code:) You have to use `bhaarat.seek(bhaarat.tell())`. Sorry

Comment: @user69498 Are you adding `out.seek(out.tell())` to your code too?

Comment: Weird... When I execute this on the console, it appears that nothing happened to either file. But when I open the files in the Finder, it appears to have worked fine.